# Выдает ошибку invalid syntax на двоеточие

Tags: python, синтаксис, syntax

```
print ("Будильник")
b==7
c==10
d==23
a=int(input("Введите время(без минут)")
if a>=b :print ("пора вставать")
else :print ("проспал")
if a<=c :print ("пора вставать")
else :print ("проспал")
if a>=d :print ("ошибка")
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Тут у вас сплошная invalid syntax ;)
Начните с форматирования кода, сами же будете тратить меньше времени на прочтение и понимание:

```
print("Будильник")

b = 7
c = 10
d = 23

a = int(input("Введите время(без минут)")

if a >= b:
    print("пора вставать")
else:
    print("проспал")

if a <= c:
    print("пора вставать")
else:
    print("проспал")

if a >= d:
    print("ошибка")
```

ps и дайте осмысленные имена переменным...

Answer (score 2):

Исправил код:

```
print ("Будильник")
b=7   # == это сравнение, а тут нужно присваивание
c=10  # == это сравнение, а тут нужно присваивание
d=23  # == это сравнение, а тут нужно присваивание
a=int(input("Введите время(без минут)")) # тут закрывающей скобки не хватало
if a>=b :print ("пора вставать")
else :print ("проспал")
if a<=c :print ("пора вставать")
else :print ("проспал")
if a>=d :print ("ошибка")
```

В остальном код диковато отформатирован, но работает. Пробелы всё же нагляднее ставить после двоеточия, а не до.